# ¿Se puede limitar la cantidad de decimales a truncar con Math.trunc() en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, math

Quiero limitar la cantidad de decimales a truncar en `Javascript` usando la función `Math.trunc()`.

Por ejemplo: si tengo el número `4.987345` y quiero que lo trunque hasta el número `7` incluido, quedando como resultado `4.98`, sin redondear cifras. No he encontrado absolutamente nada al respecto aún.

¿Es posible hacer dicha acción, es decir, limitar el número de cifras decimales a truncar en `Javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

No hay una función predefinida para hacerlo, así que lo mejor es: Transformar el número a una cadena de caracteres y luego quedarse con los decimales deseados:

```js
function dosDecimales(n) {
  let t=n.toString();
  let regex=/(\d*.\d{0,2})/;
  return t.match(regex)[0];
}

console.log(dosDecimales(3232.3456))
```

Explicación: La expresión regular se queda con números hasta que encuentra un punto. Luego se queda con los dos siguientes números que se encuentre (o menos, si no hay).

Nótese que la función devuelve un texto, no un número. Se puede transformar de nuevo a número usando la función `Number(texto)`

Answer (score 0):

No te servirá Math.trunc() ni Number.toFixed(). Podrías usar algo así:

```
var n=4.987345
var n2=parseFloat(~~n+'.'+(''+n).split('.').pop().substr(0,2));
alert(n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function truncWithoutRounding(number, decimalsAfterComma = 2){
  return parseFloat(`${(number | 0)}.${number.toString().split(".")[1].slice(0, decimalsAfterComma)}`);
}

const number = 4.987345;
const fixedNumb = truncWithoutRounding(number);
console.log(fixedNumb);
```

Tanto `toFixed` como `Math.trunc` van a redondear el numero, por lo cuál es mejor no usarlos para tu caso si no quieres que se redondeen, por ende he creado la función `truncWithoutRounding` la cuál puedes usar para ese propósito, lo que hace es redondear el numero hacia abajo, en un principio y concatener el resultado a los primeros `n` decimales que desees obtener, para ello:

```
number.toString().split(".")[1].slice(0, decimalsAfterComma)
```

Convertimos el numero completo a un `string` para con `split` dividirlo en un array de strings, el cuál la primera parte siempre contiene la parte entera, y la segunda la **parte decimal**, como nos interesa la segunda parte solamente (parte decimal), entonces accedemos a `[1]`, luego al ser este un string podemos usar el metodo `slice` para extraer desde el inicio de la cadena hasta `x` decimales que desees, cuando tengamos los decimales que deseas extraidos los concatenamos con un `.` decimal hacia la parte entera y todo esto lo volvemos a convertir a un numero decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Math.trunc(number) cortará el número donde encuentre **.**
Por lo que no lo recomiendo. No estaría tomando en cuenta el decimal.

En su lugar usaría .toFixed(3), que especifica el uso de solo 3 decimales, y si, el decimal anterior es aproximable, se aproximará.

```js
const n = 4.987345;
    
Math.trunc(n) // 4
Math.ceil(n) // 5
Math.floor(n) // 4

n.toFixed(3) // 4.987
n.toFixed(2) // 4.99
```

Tenga en cuenta que tanto ceil y floor intentarán aproximarse al entero más cercano.

Ceil al mayor, y floor al menor.

(**4.1**) para Ceil es 5 / (**4.9**) para Floor es 4.

*Trunc solo barrerá los decimales*